# Is the number of neurons in each capsule in a capsule neural network hardcoded?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, capsule-neural-network

The capsule neural networks have been formally introduced in the paper [Dynamic Routing Between Capsules](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829).

Much ado has been made about how the capsules output a vector (magnitude = probability that an entity is present, orientation space = the instantiated parameters), which can then allow it to maintain more information than a max-pooled operation which outputs only a scalar.

Within these vector representations, the dimensions of this space turn out to be the parameters by which a written digit could vary: scale, stroke thickness, skew, width, etc. There are 16 neurons in each capsule to represent 16 dimensions.

It is unclear to me, from reading the paper, if these parameters emerged through training, or if they were hand-coded a priori. If these parameters were not hand-coded, why do such "clean" dimensions emerge? Why don't mixed-selective neurons emerge within the 16?

Comment: I have changed your title to be what I think is your question. Make sure that this is the case!